# Help with "Constraint Wizard" in Vivado

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I am new with Vivado and I need help with "Constrain Wizard".

My design has as constraint a "clk" 1ns I added in the "Edit Timing Constraints", and I obtained the following result in the "Report Timing Summary". I only have in the "check timing" folder, 21 inputs delay and 41 outputs delay. The rest of them are 0.

[Timing Report Vivado]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu0Jj.png

Therefore, I need to add my contraints in both input/output Delays in the "Constraint Wizard" tool.

[Constraint Wizard Input Delays]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmZQY.png

Please, I really need help with this:

1.How can I calculate/obtain the values for the constraint Wizard? "tco_min", "tco_max", "trce_dly_min", "trce_dly_max".
2. This values in the constraint wizard as far as I understand will fix my timing errors in the first picture, am I right?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited my question